# Video to webp converter software

Tags: animation, video, codec, converters, webp

I need to convert several videos to animated webp format, but I found no software to handle it.
There are some online tools, but they are either paid or work with restrictions like low resolution and fps.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Though didn't find a software with GUI that can to the converting, I tried the ffmpeg CLI method and it works for me.

### 1. Install ffmpeg CLI through homebrew

In terminal.app, install ffmpeg through homebrew

```
brew install ffmpeg
```

Validate the installation:

```
which ffmpeg
```

Expect to see terminal returns the directory path of ffmpeg such as `/usr/local/bin/ffmpeg`

### 2. Run and convert

Example command which would convert an mp4 file to a lossless loop playing webp file in 20FPS with resolution 800px(width) * h600px(height):

```
ffmpeg -i input_filename.mp4 -vcodec libwebp -filter:v fps=fps=20 -lossless 1 -loop 0 -preset default -an -vsync 0 -s 800:600 output_filename.webp
```

#### primary options:

- set frame per second as 20: `-filter:v fps=fps=20`
- set output file lossless: `-lossless 1`
- set output webp file loop play: `-loop 0`. For non-loop, use `-loop 1`
- set rendering mode `-preset default` , can set as `picture`, `photo`, `text`, `icon`, `drawing` and `none` as needed. It would effect output file size. http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#Options-28
- set output webp resolution as w800px * h600px `-s 800:600`

For more option details, please visit the [the ffmpeg libwebp documentation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-all.html#libwebp)

This method should applicable for majority video formats including .mov, .avi, .flv, etc. as input files as well as .gif format as output file.

Noted this on my gist: https://gist.github.com/witmin/1edf926c2886d5c8d9b264d70baf7379

Comment: Is the webp supposed to be bigger in size compared to the original size of the mp4 ? I have a 780kb mp4 that is turning into a 6mb video with the same commands you posted.

Comment: @zd5151 yes it could be bigger if -lossless, bigger resolution or higher frame rate. The fps may effect the most.

Comment: @Milllie when i convert mp4 to animated webp it increases size from 500kb to 1.5mb, any suggestion or solution?

Comment: @Addy unfortunately I also met the same problem :(